# Bing image as lockscreen for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, lock-screen, bing

[Bing my lockscreen](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-us/app/bing-my-lockscreen/7e1f890f-8960-43e5-a258-58ba3eeb1163) is an application for Windows 8 which sets the lockscreen to the Bing wallpaper of that day.

Is there any similar application or method by which my Windows 7 lockscreen can be set to the Bing image of that day?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mouse without Borders to do this.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.howtogeek.com/112110/how-to-set-a-custom-logon-screen-background-on-windows-7/) might be helpful, but it is just to set your lockscreen to an image - if, perhaps, you wrote a script that downloaded the picture at midnight (or whenever the image updates) you could just have the script replace the current picture with the newly downloaded one, and it should update the lock screen.

This might be able to do the downloading for you - http://bing.codeplex.com/